# HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) radio station audio stream with timed metadata "in the wild"

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I have been unable to find a radio station streaming with HLS that uses timed metadata.  I have found many HLS streams, but none with actual metadata in the stream.  I need to find an existing stream for testing.

Any suggestions for a station, or how to find one?

Comment: Any update on this?  I am trying to finda way to get audio metadata information from  a live stream using hls js.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a radio station, but Apple's [developer resources for HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) includes two [example streams](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/). The "advanced" stream mentions including timed metadata featuring a timecode every five seconds.